Visual studio code "Rename Symbol" doesn't work when the new name includes points
I'm working in godot (c#), and I basically have a bunch of booleans to represent the state of my characters. In order to handle these more easily, I decided to move them into a new resource class, called "stateVars", and just make a variable of that class in the charactrer script.
Of course, to do that I need to rename all references to the variable, so for example "onFloor", should become "stateVars.onFloor". But when I use rename symbol to do just that, it returns "no result", and doesn't change anything. I understand that "Rename symbol" probably wants a valid symbol, which excludes points, spaces etc. But is there another way to do this?
I tried using "Change all occurences", but it seems to only affect the current file, and given that these variables are used pretty often,it would still take a while to rename them everywhere I need.

In VS Code, you can find all the occurrences in the Search section, and replace them with a new word:

Don't forget to click on both filter buttons Aa and ab (right side) to search for the exact word "onFloor"

This seems to have the same problem as "Change all occurences", in that it only changes the occurences in the current file.

If a folder is opened with VS Code, then the technique that I showed will search across the folder, and not in one file only. Do you have your folder opened in VS Code?

Yeah, all the files show up in the side bar, and "Rename Symbol" changes all instances across all files if the new symbol is valid.

Great. If it worked, please approve this answer, so for other people to know that the answer is helpful. Thanks

It doesn't work, as the symbol I'm trying to change it to includes a ".", which seems to make the new symbol invalid.
